# React navigation v5 getting initialParams prop on Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have tried many times to get `initialParams` with `this.props.navigation.state.params`. It wasn't helpful. Help me please how to get these params.

```
<Stack.Screen name="FromMainScreenToSubCats" component={FromMainScreenToSubCats} initialParams={{catId:1 , title:'Filmler'}} />
```

Comment: For your next question, you may want to tag your question with react-navigation so more people can see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access params with `this.props.route.params`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/upgrading-from-4.x.html#separate-route-prop